# NSDate not Formatted and getting as nil

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting date from another uiview and set the format of date and add in event.

But, it is giving nil.

Here is my code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:eventDate];
```

and here is log

```
  (lldb) po eventDate
  $0 = 0x0b555f60 2013-04-19
  (lldb) po [formatter dateFromString:eventDate]
  $1 = 0x00000000 <nil>
  (lldb)
```

Help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Your string's format and the format you specify in the date formatter must match.

Set your date formatter's format to `yyyy-MM-dd` to match the string you wish to convert to a date.

Comment: But now it showing day before date like this.Why?   (lldb) po eventDate
$0 = 0x0a784120 2013-04-19
(lldb) po [formatter dateFromString:eventDate]
$1 = 0x0b44d790 2013-04-18 18:30:00 +0000
(lldb)

Comment: When you log an NSDate object, you always get that same fixed format. Note the timezone is UTC (+0000). What you are seeing is correct.